# Flutter initialization filed

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have done a flutter app with a code where the user can select gender from 2 cards and the GestureDetector the android studio don't give me any error but when I try to test the app I recive this error on device
LateInitilizationError: Field 'selectedGender' has not been initialized

here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'icon_content.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';

const bottomContainerHeight = 80.0;
const activeCardColour = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColour = Color(0xFF111328);
const bottomContainerColour = Color(0XFFEB1555);

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  InputPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  late Gender selectedGender;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                        ? activeCardColour
                        : inactiveCardColour,
                    cardChild: IconContent(
                      customIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                      customText: ('MALE'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                        ? activeCardColour
                        : inactiveCardColour,
                    cardChild: IconContent(
                      customIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                      customText: ('FEMALE'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                  onPress: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  colour: activeCardColour,
                  cardChild: Column()),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                      onPress: () {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      colour: activeCardColour,
                      cardChild: Column()),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                        onPress: () {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        colour: activeCardColour,
                        cardChild: Column())),
              ],
            )),
            Container(
              color: bottomContainerColour,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: bottomContainerHeight,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

i try to search about flutter docs testing erros as device told to me but i find a solution

Answer (score 1):

`late` is simply saying that this value will be initialized before read. Simple way to handle this situation will be making nullable

`Gender? selectedGender;` the rest of your code will be ok with it.

More about [late-variables](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables)

**Test Widget**

```dart
class _APPState extends State<APP> {
  Gender? selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.female;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: selectedGender == Gender.female
                      ? Colors.green
                      // activeCardColour
                      : inactiveCardColour,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.male;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: selectedGender == Gender.male
                      ? Colors.green
                      // activeCardColour
                      : inactiveCardColour,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But so the card don't change :(
the code don't work as i need

Comment: It will change while you select a gender from press, else both of them are unselected and will have `inactiveCardColour`. Does it work by tapping one?

Comment: Nope don't work ic an select nothing

Comment: `activeCardColour` and `inactiveCardColour` are quite the same, i've tested with my widget, should I include that as well?

Comment: i have e list of 40 error copiling 
 Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/.bmi_calculato(17354): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/.bmi_calculato(17354): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/.bmi_calculato(17354): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;-..
...'!_needsLayout': is not true.

Comment: Do a `flutter clean` and restart

Comment: I try to do a flutter clean but i see in your code you use onTap i use onPress maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Both are quite the same bro, just one with known by different names for different widget.

Comment: I know but i home that's can be the problem becouse after clean i recive this error and still don't work :(
W/.bmi_calculato(17769): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getUnsafe()Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/.bmi_calculato(17769): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/.bmi_calculato(17769): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;-......

Comment: also could be issue on different widget tree, you can try using key on `ReusableCard`'s parrent.

Comment: I have an dart file for reusable_card but i don't think i can use this there becouse there is not logic part in this file

Comment: From your question, I was able to produce this issue and solved it this way. You might need to create a separate question about new errors, including those snippets that will reproduce the errors.

Answer (score 0):

From your first row you have this

```
colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
        ? activeCardColour
        : inactiveCardColour,
```

here the value of `selectedGender` is null at first launch. You need to set a value for this property.

Comment: Sorry but i would to don't have a choise when the app start.... it can't be possible?

Comment: Then you need to check if `selectedGender` is null or not by `(selectedGender ?? Gender.male) == Gender.male`

Comment: Don't work so i have a new variable type bool